# Using BETWEEN clause in Plotalot

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5, between

Trying to create league tables and display using Plotalot graphs. I'm using the BETWEEN clause but I don't seem to get the result I expect, which is ...no results! Would be grateful for support with this.

Code is

```
SELECT FieldName, COUNT(FieldValue) AS "Total" 
FROM jos_rsform_submission_values 
WHERE FieldName LIKE'Goals' AND "Total" BETWEEN 1 AND 20 ORDER BY Total DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you allready know that there should be results with the `WHERE` syntax used.

Try without the ""

```
SELECT FieldName, COUNT(FieldValue) `Total`
FROM jos_rsform_submission_values 
WHERE FieldName LIKE 'Goals' AND Total BETWEEN 1 AND 20 ORDER BY Total DESC
```

It could also be done using a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM
(    
SELECT FieldName, COUNT(FieldValue)  `Total`
FROM jos_rsform_submission_values 
WHERE FieldName LIKE 'Goals' 
) Sub WHERE Sub.Total BETWEEN 1 AND 20 
ORDER BY Sub.Total DESC
```

Try this query to make sure you have matchtes of total between 1 and 20

```
    SELECT FieldName, COUNT(FieldValue)  `Total`
    FROM jos_rsform_submission_values 
    GROUP BY FieldName
```

Comment: Thank you. Using the first query returns

"Plotalot error: Plot 2: Unknown column 'Total' in 'where clause' [1054]"

The second query returns

"Plotalot error: This chart requires 2 columns
Plotalot warning: Plot 2: No rows"

Comment: This means that there are no matches on your query. Are you sure there are rows that matches your critera? Try the new query i edited in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I already have output of 20 `FieldValues` in descending order. The difficulty is in changing 20 to 80 and then dividing the 80 into 4 groups of 20 to make Leagues 1,2,3 and 4. This is why I thought the BETWEEN clause would work! Here's the working graph http://welfarecentral.org/1/